# AWQL Adwords Api, get Costs Adsgroup?

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

i made a php script to get the cost for each of my `adsgroug`. It was working before but know, it's sounds like if it's always works but my cost dont have any sense.

For example for an `adsgroup` width `1.18€` cost for `1 day`, i get `10000 0_0`.

This is my request

```
$reportDefinition = '
SELECT CampaignName,AdGroupName, Impressions, Clicks, Cost

FROM ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT

WHERE Cost>0
  AND CampaignName CONTAINS "DSA"

DURING '.$date.','.$date;
```

i dont really understand this, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

They recently switched the default to return in 'Micros'.

All this means is that you simply need to divide the value they give you by 1,000,000 to get the the € amount.

ref:

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting-concepts

(scroll down till you get to the section: Money fields in reports)